# Not getting correct PRIMARY KEY

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

After going to the profile link: **http://127.0.0.1:8000/basic_app/profile/3/**
[image]

---

Then trying the link: **http://127.0.0.1:8000/basic_app/profile/2/** It is working. So there must be some issue with primary key. And I figured out that this is happening after creating a superuser.
[image]

---

### models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Create your models here.
BLOOD_CHOICES = (
    ('o+', 'O+'),
    ('o-', 'O-'),
    ('a+', 'A+'),
    ('a-', 'A-'),
    ('b+', 'B+'),
    ('b-', 'B-'),
    ('ab+', 'AB+'),
    ('ab-', 'AB-'),
)


class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # additional
    last_date = models.DateField(blank=False)
    contact_no = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    blood_group = models.CharField(
        max_length=4, choices=BLOOD_CHOICES, default='o+')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

---

### forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import UserProfileInfo


class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password')

        widgets = {
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder':'First Name'}),
            'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder':'Last Name'}),
            'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder':'Choose an Username'}),
            'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder':'Your Email'}),
            'password': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder':'Your Password'})
        }


class UserProfileInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = UserProfileInfo
        fields = ('contact_no', 'blood_group', 'last_date')

        widgets = {
            'contact_no': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder':'Your Personal Phone Number'}),
            'blood_group': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder':'Your Blood Group'}),
            'last_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder':'The last date you donated blood'}),
        }
```

---

### basic_app/urls

```
from django.urls import path
from basic_app import views

app_name = 'basic_app'

urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
    path('user_login/', views.user_login, name='user_login'),
    path('profile/<int:pk>/',
         views.ProfileDetailView.as_view(), name='profile'),
]
```

---

### views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import UserForm, UserProfileInfoForm

#
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

#
from django.views.generic import (View, TemplateView,
                                  ListView, DetailView,
                                  CreateView, UpdateView,
                                  DeleteView)

from . import models

# Create your views here.


class ProfileDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'profile_detail'
    model = models.UserProfileInfo
    template_name = 'basic_app/profile.html'


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'basic_app/index.html')


@login_required
def special(request):
    return HttpResponse("You are logged in.")


@login_required
def user_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))


def register(request):

    registered = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm(data=request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():

            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user

            if 'last_date' and 'contact_no' and 'blood_group' in request.POST:
                print('found it')
                # If yes, then grab it from the POST form reply
                profile.last_date = request.POST['last_date']
                profile.contact_no = request.POST['contact_no']
                profile.blood_group = request.POST['blood_group']

            # Now save model
            profile.save()

            # Registration Successful!
            registered = True
        else:
            # One of the forms was invalid if this else gets called.
            print(user_form.errors, profile_form.errors)

    else:
        # Was not an HTTP post so we just render the forms as blank.
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm()

    return render(request, 'basic_app/registration.html',
                  {'user_form': user_form,
                   'profile_form': profile_form,
                   'registered': registered})


def user_login(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))

            else:
                return HttpResponse("Account not active")

        else:
            print("Someone tried to login and failed")
            print("Username: {} and password()".format(username, password))
            return HttpResponse("Invalid login details supplied")
    else:
        return render(request, 'basic_app/login.html', {})
```

---

### base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Blood Donation</title>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/master.css'%}">


</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'index' %}">Blood<span>Donation</span></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item item-one active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'index' %}">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Search</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <div class="">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <!-- <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'basic_app:register' %}">Register</a></li> -->
                        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link"
                                href="{% url 'basic_app:profile' pk=user.id %}">Profile</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a></li>
                        {% else %}
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'basic_app:register' %}">Register</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'basic_app:user_login' %}">Login</a></li>
                        {% endif %}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">

        {% block body_block %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>

 

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simply that you have no profile where `id == 3`

To verify this, go into the django admin panel and look at your profile table (if you've not added this model to the admin, you may need to do so first before you can see it).

Alternativly open a django shell and select all records from the model, you should see there is no record for id == 3.

Edit: To be clear. `User` is not `UserProfileInfo`.

You may well have a user with id == 3, but that does not mean you have a UserProfileInfo with this ID, and it is `UserProfileInfo` that is the model for your view, not `User`.

In fact, the id for `UserProfileInfo` does not have to match that for `User`, and quite possibly won't, especially if the first thing you did was create a superuser ... then they'll be out of sync.

My guess is you have something like this:

```
User name      User ID     UserProfileInfo ID
 superuser        1        
 user1            2              1
 user2            3              2
```

Comment: Yes there is no profile where `id == 3`. While registering data it went for `id == 2`. But at the same time while going to profile link it is accessing for `id == 3`. Can you please tell, Why?

Comment: and if there is no `id==3` why is it passing `id == 3`, in base.html using `pk=user.id`?

Comment: @SJMormo I added a little more explanation to my answer ...

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand the problem. Can you please give me any suggestion, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: It's not a problem ... You don't have a UserProfileInfo record for id==3, so you should get a 404, which you are.